# threadpool class not specified error

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I got an error after initalized StdSchedulerFactory while getting scheduler object.

`init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: ThreadPool class not specified.`

code is :

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", name);
    properties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", String.valueOf(numberOfThreads));
    properties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck", "true");

    StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    stdSchedulerFactory.initialize(properties);
    Scheduler scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
```

Could you suggest any solution?

Comment: "Could you suggest any solution?" <-- without the code, no...

Comment: You should show how you configure Quartz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need at least this:

```
properties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.class", "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
```

You might need to look at some quartz examples and configure more properties.